# hello worldが出力されない

Tags: c++, visual-studio

プログラム勉強はじめたてです。Visual studio C++の質問です。
画像の赤い線で囲われた部分が「hello world」と出力するプログラムです。

[image]

```
 :
 :
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: HDC を使用する描画コードをここに追加してください...

        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;

        int main() {
            cout << "HelloWorld." << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
 :
 :
```

C++言語でhello worldと出力されるように入力してデバックしたんですが、出力されません。
どこが間違っているか教えてください。

ちなみに、このプログラムは下のサイトに載っていた通り入力しました。
http://cpp-lang.sevendays-study.com/day1.html

本当にプログラムに関して知らないことだらけ色々教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　今回は構いませんが、次回以降はソースコードはスクリーンショットだけでなくそのものをコピー＆ペーストして頂けるとありがたいです。ソースコードの中身で検索できるようになりますし、回答しようとする人が手元で試す際にソースコードをコピペでき、再現しやすくなります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**端的な回答**：Visual Studio のプロジェクトを作る所からやり直し、プロジェクトの種類を「空のプロジェクト」から始めてください。

**詳しい回答**：

おそらく、Visual Studio の新規プロジェクト作成で Windows デスクトップアプリケーションを作ったときに自動生成されたプログラムに、ウェブサイトで見た Hello World のプログラムを追記されたのだと思います。

今回の場合、この追記が上手くいっていません。プログラムの意味と関係なくふたつのプログラムが融合しただけで、うまく解釈できるプログラムになっていません。

今回参考にされたプログラムは、他にソースコードが必要ない、そのままこれだけで動くプログラムです。つまり、最終的には `helloworld.cpp` に次のように書かれているだけで上手く動きます。他にソースコードは必要ありません。

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio でこのような構成のプロジェクトを作るには、以下のようにします。

1. 「空のプロジェクト」としてプロジェクトを新規作成する。
2. 「プロジェクト」→「新しい項目の追加」→「C++ファイル」から新しいファイルをひとつ追加する。
3. ソースコードを書く。

---

<sub>今は読まなくて良い補足：実際に複雑なプログラムを書く際には `using namespace std;` はお行儀が良くないとされることが多いです。今は良いですが、将来的には「using namespace std 避ける」などで検索して長所短所を理解してみてください。</sub>